# Image Not Showing in Twitter Bootstrap Template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first time using bootstrap but for some reason I can't get my image to show. Instead, the default background image appears even though there is no reference to the file in the html or the css.

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWS7I.png)

Comment: is your image store in a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `background-image` css tag has the error.
If you remove the no-repeat in it, you will have the image follow the `background-size: cover;` work.

Also, try removing the 'background-color: black;', to see if that helps.